# Automatic loading of templates in django is not working for my app

Tags: python, django

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders), django should load templates automatically from my app if i have a folder named 'templates' in the root dir of the app.

I've added my app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    # Use email as username https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username
     'emailusernames',
     'purchaseapp' # this is my app
)
```

I've created a templates folder

[image]

and i've setup urlpatterns to use the admin as the login page

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'timely.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^timely/', include('timely.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', hello),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
    url(r'^accounts/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/'}),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/'}),
)
```

i overwrote base_site.html but i can't see my customization, which i see if it add the folder to TEMPLATE_DIRS

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/Users/nicola/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/timely/purchaseapp/templates",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, maybe you will wish to add django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader to your template loaders to load templates from apps without choosing each in TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Comment: I had faced similar problem, adding template folder to root of project AND in the app folder solved my problem.

Comment: @simplylizz no i already have that, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @vedarthk i fixed the issue it was a kind of priority problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that probably django stops searching when it founds a valid template so my app had to come first than the contrib admin

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'purchaseapp', #this is my app
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    # Use email as username https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username
     'emailusernames',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a few more directories under admin (from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories)):

> In order to override one or more of them, first create an admin
>   directory in your project's templates directory. This can be any of
>   the directories you specified in TEMPLATE_DIRS.
>
> Within this admin directory, create sub-directories named after your
>   app. Within these app subdirectories create sub-directories named
>   after your models. Note, that the admin app will lowercase the model
>   name when looking for the directory, so make sure you name the
>   directory in all lowercase if you are going to run your app on a
>   case-sensitive filesystem.
>
> To override an admin template for a specific app, copy and edit the
>   template from the django/contrib/admin/templates/admin directory, and
>   save it to one of the directories you just created.

Comment: What folders exactly?I added purchaseapp folder under admin and moved files there but still no success.

Comment: That applies to overriding admin pages for only for specific models (eg an override on an add page). For site-wide changes to base_site.html, index.html and login.html Nicola's structure looks right.

Comment: @AidanEwen in the end it was just a problem of order of INSTALLED_APPS